# Add Section in listview

Tags: android, listview, custom-lists

I'm stuck to add section in list view. Can somebody give me tips or link related to add section in mylistview. For note I have been searched and found the module -[here](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/listview-with-section-header-in-android) the module- but somehow the module isn't compatible or doesn't match with my existing module. See my code.

you can see my class was extends ArrayAdapter, not baseadapter. What can I do to customize the code?

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

ArrayList<Item> profileList = new ArrayList<>();

public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Item> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    profileList = objects;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return super.getCount();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_items, null);
    TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    System.out.println(position);
    textView.setText(profileList.get(position).getProfileItem());
    imageView.setImageResource(profileList.get(position).getProfileImage());
    return v;

}
```

}

and from Fragment

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    //List View for profile user
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listProfile);
    proflieList.add(new Item("Profile", R.drawable.ic_person_black_24dp));
    proflieList.add(new Item("Housing", R.drawable.ic_hotel_black_24dp));
    //proflieList.add(new Item("Bantuan", R.drawable.ic_action_tv));
    //proflieList.add(new Item("Versi aplikasi", R.drawable.ic_action_tv));
    sAdapter = new SectionAdapter(getActivity());
    sAdapter.addSectionHeaderItem("Section");

    CustomArrayAdapter myadapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_view_items, proflieList);
    listView.setAdapter(myadapter);
```

can someone help so I can put section on my list view ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you are trying to pull here but you can use this lib: 
https://github.com/beworker/pinned-section-listview